# How to install gpt fdisk 8.4 in Kubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, deb, fdisk, gpt

I'm using Kubuntu 12.04 (64bit). The Ubuntu repos contain gpt fdisk 8.1 which is not the latest. The latest version is 8.4 and it contains [some bug fixes](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/revisions.html) I want to have.

I downloaded the latest deb package from here: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/srs5694/xUbuntu_11.10/amd64/gptfdisk_0.8.4-1_amd64.deb

When I tried to install it initially, I got an error that dependencies could not be satisfied. So I installed the version from the repos first, then tried to install the latest version over that. Now I get the error below.

```
# dpkg -i gptfdisk_0.8.4-1_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package gptfdisk.
(Reading database ... 90031 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking gptfdisk (from gptfdisk_0.8.4-1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing gptfdisk_0.8.4-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man8/cgdisk.8.gz', which is also in package gdisk 0.8.1-1build1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gptfdisk_0.8.4-1_amd64.deb
```

How can I install 8.4 of gpt fdisk?

Comment: I had the same problem, yesterday. The problem is that the latest gptfdisk has a dependency on a library (libicu44) that does not exist in 12.04. My guess is that the library has been superceded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is available here now:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdisk/0.8.4-1
“gdisk” 0.8.4-1 source package in Ubuntu

Ubuntu “gdisk” package - 0.8.4-1

- New upstream release:

  - Fix FTBFS with gcc-4.7 (Closes: #667177)
  - Drop debian/patches/eof_stdin.diff, accepted upstream
  - Refresh debian/patches/manpages.diff (minor typo fixed upstream)

Uploaded by:
    Guillaume Delacour on 2012-04-20

Answer (score 1):

libicu44, I downloaded this one. It installed fine.

http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu//pool/main/i/icu/libicu44_4.4.2-2ubuntu0.11.10.1_amd64.deb

Comment: that's not a deb package to install gpt fdisk. I think you answered the wrong question.